# How do I get money on and off of harborly?

Tags: litecoin, buy-bitcoins, canada

I signed up for a [harborly](https://harbor.ly/) account but I'm still not quite sure how it works. I would like to buy some bitcoins, but how do I get money onto the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store your fiat currency directly on harborly. They're a lot like [coinbase](https://coinbase.com/) in that they allow you to sync your bank accounts with your wallet. Instead of sending money to them, then buying and selling, whenever you buy or sell they directly credit or debit your synced bank account.